# jqGrid's setSelect does not work after reloadGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

setSelection does not select the row, whose id is 2, right after a reloadGrid.

```
    $("#training").setGridParam({url: 'index.php?func=trainingmgr&aAction=refreshData'});
    $("#training").trigger("reloadGrid");
    $("#training").jqGrid('setSelection', "2″);
```

However, setSelection can select the row, whose id is 2, when you take this line out: $("#training").trigger("reloadGrid");

Anybody experiences the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should select row after the jqGrid will be filled. So you should place

```
 $("#training").jqGrid('setSelection', "2");
```

inside of `loadComplete` event handler and not call this immediately after  `$("#training").trigger("reloadGrid");` because `trigger` call `jQuery.ajax` which work asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

In several places in my application I am calling `reloadGrid` followed by `setSelection`, and the row is being selected successfully. Something else must be going on with your application. Did you try running this in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if any errors are being thrown?